# React child component doesnt render where it should

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I'm building an app and I want to render components with position:"fixed" with given x positions on the screen, each component should then calculate the top/left properties from x before rendering. But when I add a component it seems to render before the style object is calculated. The position of each child should change when a new one is added to the array in the parent component.

This is the parent component the calls the childrens

```
{players.map((player, i) => {
            let positions = playerPosition(players.length);
            let x = positions[i][0];
            let place = positions[i][1];
            return (
                <Player key={i} x={x} placement={place}></Player>

            )
        })}
```

This is the child component

```
export default function Player({ playerObject, x, placement }){
const classes = useStyles();
const [position, setPosition] = useState();
const [size, setSize] = useState({height:10, width:10});
const [xPos, setXPos] = useState();
const [yPos, setYPos] = useState();
var y;
const [style, setStyle] = useState();


useEffect(() => {
    setXPos(x);
    y = findPlayerYPos(x);
    setYPos(y)
    setStyle({
        position: 'fixed',
        width: size.width,
        height: size.height,
        top: y - size.height / 2 + window.innerHeight / 2,
        left: x - size.width / 2 + window.innerWidth / 2,
    })
}, [x])

return (
    <Paper
    className={classes.paper}
    style={style}
    ></Paper>
)
```

}
When there is only 1 player to render it is fine but when I update the players array they all render at the middle of the screen (x=0, y=0).
I did console.log my y from findPlayerYPos and it is what it should be but the component seems to render before it is defined.

Comment: Try not to use index of an array as a key. If order of your players will change, it will mess up your state. Also set initial X and Y to `0`, so it would not be undefined when players first render. It most definitely will not help, but at least your code will be more predictable

Comment: There are multiple issues with the code. One is that you are using state variables in your effect that you did not include in the dependency array. Because of this, it will not be called again, when one of those changes. This may be the reason for your problem when adding a player. Every prop or state, that is used by the effect should be included in the dependency array.